# addEventListener in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, dom-events

I am following a tutorial on Lynda.com about the new DOM event model.

This is the code I am working with.

```
function addEventHandler(oNode, sEvt, fFunc, bCapture){

if (typeof (window.event) != "undefined")
    oNode.attachEvent("on" + sEvt, fFunc);
else
    oNode.addEventListener(sEvt, fFunc, bCapture);
}

function onLinkClicked(e){
alert('You clicked the link');
}

function setUpClickHandler(){
addEventHandler(document.getElementById("clickLink"), "click", onLinkClicked, false);
}


addEventHandler(window, "load", setUpClickHandler, false);
```

I am adding it to the click event on this link

```
<a href="#" title="click me" id="clickLink">Click Me!</a>
```

It works perfectly fine in IE, Firefox, Opera but not in Chrome. I've looked around, but have not been able to find anything specific yet. Some similar questions but it does not answer my question.

I get the following error from the Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attachEvent'

Any suggestions or a link to the answer?

Comment: That's a bad tutorial and clearly shows the danger of testing for the existence of an object other than the one you want to use. `if (typeof oNode.attachEvent != "undefined")` would be better. Better still would be to prefer the standards-based function `addEventListener` by testing for that first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you testing:

```
if (typeof (window.event) != "undefined")
```

...in order to decide whether to use `attachEvent()`? Chrome does define `window.event`, so then your code tries to use `attachEvent()` which is not defined.

Try instead testing for the method directly:

```
if (oNode.attachEvent)
    oNode.attachEvent("on" + sEvt, fFunc);
else
    oNode.addEventListener(sEvt, fFunc, bCapture);
```

Comment: thanks, I just started looking into the new DOM event model, and this is what the instructor in the course is testing for, but it is from 2009. But your answer is perfect, it didn't make much sense to me either. Why does that test not work on Chrome though, it works on all other browsers? But your answer works, thanks I'm also curious why it doesn't just skip it and move on to the else statement.

Comment: The code you showed didn't make sense in 2009 either. As I said in my answer, Chrome defines `window.event`, so the `if` condition will be true in Chrome resulting in an attempt to use `.attachEvent()` which is not defined in Chrome (as indicated by the text of the error you mentioned). The original code works in IE because it defines both `window.event` and `.attachEvent()`, and works in FF, etc., because it doesn't define `window.event`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Missed it in the first comment.