# Window properties as JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript

**Update:
This problem seems to have disappeared in Chrome 33.**

Can properties of the window object (name, screen in the example below) be used as JavaScript variables? In FireFox it works as expected but not so in Chrome. Why?

html:

```
<input type="button" id="name" value="name before">
<input type="button" id="screen" value="screen before">
```

js:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var screen = document.getElementById('screen');

console.log(name);
console.log(screen);

name.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    name.value = "after";
});

screen.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    screen.value = "after";
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should every JavaScript programmer know?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know)

Comment: Where are you accessing `window` properties?

Comment: duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968224/addeventlistener-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @Barmar: name and screen are both properties of the window object. I guess window.name and my variable name collide. Firefox take one path, Chrome the other.